# integer values in NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to take 4 random numbers and save it into an `NSSet` ( to ensure that same number is not in the array)

As the `int` values has to be `NSNumber` object and hence cannot compare, it is not able to save unique integer in array.

```
+(NSMutableSet *)uniquenumber
{
    int j=0;
    NSMutableSet *sets=[[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
    while (sets.count<4) {
        j=arc4random()%7;
        [sets addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:j]];
    }
    return sets;
}
```

I want to get 4 unique number randomly from `0-7`. Thats the problem.

Appreciate your help and suggestions to improve the code.

Comment: Did you even try your own code? It works fine!

Comment: I would suggest use C++'s std::set<int>.

Comment: Please provide a link on how to embed C++ in Obj-C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Marc Mosby recommend, i edited my answer:

**Updated Answer:**

```
int j = 0;
NSMutableSet *set= [NSMutableSet set];

while (set.count < 4) {
    j = arc4random_uniform(7);
    [set addObject:@(j)];
}

NSArray *array = set.allObjects;
```

Comment: Because your answer is waaay too complicated. You basically implement an NSSet (so just use NSSet) and never use default methods (your inner for loop could be replaced with array contains:). Also the best answer would be "use your existing code because it works". (btw I did not downvote you, but I can understand the one who did it)

Comment: as a part of the question ,"it is not able to save unique integer in array", i did that to solve the NSArray unique integer problem !!!

Comment: Then: Use the original solution and do: `NSArray *array = [set allObjects]`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as my answer was accepted, i had to modify it considering your recommendations

Comment: thanks marc mosby for ur valuable answers.

Answer (score 1):

This code is fine. `NSNumber` won't be added to `NSMutableSet` if equal value already exists there.
Look here if not sure: [NSMutableSet contains Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488211/nsmutableset-contains-duplicates)

Comment: That's not what that linked article says, it says you need to override the comparisons.